# php mysqli_fetch_assoc only fetching one row

Tags: php

Trying to work within a WP db outside of wp site.

```
$e = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'mls_email'";

$er = mysqli_query($wp,$e);
$ed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($er);


if(isset($_GET['test'])){

    print_r($ed);

}
```

When I `print_r`, I only get a single result.  If I run the query in the console, I get the expected result.  Does `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only fetch one row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL not pulling all rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485016/mysql-not-pulling-all-rows)

Comment: Just so OP stops getting slammed with downvotes... [he did try to set it up correctly but had some infinite loop issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078703/php-mysqli-fetch-assoc-only-fetching-one-row/20078735#comment29912013_20078735)

Comment: No; you don't deserve to be treated rudely, @tPlummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only fetches one row at a time so you have to loop through them like this:

```
$e = "SELECT `meta_value` 
       FROM  `wp_usermeta` 
       WHERE `meta_key` = 'mls_email'";

$er = mysqli_query($wp,$e);

while ( $ed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($er) )
{
   // loop through result set 
   print "<pre>" . print_r($ed,true) . "</pre>"; 
}
```

[mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)

Comment: Ah, I tried this earlier but had it set up wrong and it just did an infinite loop.

Comment: it will run out when the data does... it will loop for each row in the result.

Comment: Next time, you should include everything you attempted in your post.  It will prevent some of the downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, kinda got blasted for that one.  Kinda deserved it though, too.